# how can I display all function name from cscope database?

Tags: cscope

I am trying to find a way to dump ALL the functions name and it's path from [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) database. Is there a way to do that from cscope CLI?

Note: the [cscope source code is available for download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cscope/files/latest/download?source=files).

Comment: did the answer covered your question? If yes please consider marking the answer as answered.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following:

```
cscope -R -L -2 ".*" | awk -F ' ' '{print $2 "#" $1}' | sort | uniq
```

1. The command `cscope -R -L -2 ".*"` will output functions called by
   any function (see explanation of the options below). For each reference found, `cscope` outputs a line consisting of the file name, function name, line number, and line text, separated by spaces.
2. Use `awk` to extract the function name `$2` and file name `$1` separated by `#`. Change `$2`, `$1` and the separator `#` if you need other output fields or separator.
3. Sort the output with `sort`.
4. Get unique items with `uniq`.

`cscope` options (see http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_man_page.html):

- `-R` Recurse subdirectories for source files.
- `-L` Do a single search with line-oriented output when used with the
  -num pattern option.
- `-2 ".*"` Go to input field num (here 0-based field 2) and find
  pattern (here `.*` for all). You can see the input fields in cscope's screen mode. This may vary depending on the version you are using. The fields for version 15.8a under debian are:

  - 0: Find this C symbol:
  - 1: Find this global definition:
  - 2: Find functions called by this function:
  - 3: Find functions calling this function:
  - 4: Find this text string:
  - 5: Change this text string:
  - 6: Find this egrep pattern:
  - 7: Find this file:
  - 8: Find files #including this file:

Comment: Is there any way how to find all function onyl from one file/module?

Comment: This is great explanation of line-oriented interface! Thanks for that!