# Find all functions in a C file

Tags: ctags, cscope

I need a script to get list of all functions from one particular file.
Here is similar question and response for *cscope* tool.

[how can I display all function name from cscope database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766566/how-can-i-display-all-function-name-from-cscope-database)

I've tried to do it this way, but I get all functions in a project and I am not able to assign them to right file.

Any idea how to get just all functions of a specified C file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -b option to cscope and just build the cross ref db the first time, and then use the mechanism in the link you specified, but don't use the -R option.  Make it use the db you've already built.

```
find . -name foo.c > cscope.files

cscope -b
```